# LVM thinpool thinvolume free blocks, reclaim space

Tags: linux, disk-space, lvm

I use LVM thinvolumes to network boot a bunch of computers via iSCSI. From time to time I free up space on that machines. Unfortunatelly, that space isn't freed on the thinvolumes. So I `partclone` the partitions from time to time, to free up space.
In virtualization, you can use tools that zero unused space, which frees it. Is there a similar or better way for reclaiming space with LVM thin pools / thin volumes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

LVM thin supports DISCARD, more broadly known as TRIM. It should theoretically be possible to somehow make this work with iSCSI (there’s an equivalent UNMAP command), but I haven’t found anything on that.

On the machine hosting those volumes, you can use `fstrim` to release free space. The man page even mentions it explicitly:

> fstrim is used on a mounted filesystem to discard (or "trim") blocks which are not in use by the filesystem.  This is useful for solid-state drives (SSDs) and thinly-provisioned storage.

For this to work, Linux needs support for the filesystem and that support needs to include TRIM. If your network-booted computers run Windows, it’s probably NTFS. Apparently NTFS-3G supports TRIM.

`fstrim` operates on mounted filesystems only.

It’ll look like this:

[image: DISCARD demo]

**Update**: As discussed in the comments, the Linux SCSI Target offers a flag on its block backstores that identifies SSDs: `is_nonrot`. It also supports the UNMAP SCSI command. Windows (at least Windows 10) correctly detects SSDs over iSCSI and issues UNMAP commands, freeing unused space immediately.

Comment: Yes, works great. Thank you, excellent answer. Unfortunatelly it did not work with NTFS-3G or from one of the remote booted computers using suspect tool ForceTrim.exe found on the internet. I guess, when I manage my iSCSI Target software on linux LIO to expose the thin volumes as SSD, Windows would do the job for me and avoid doing it's automatic defragmentation.
    mixi@u0:/mnt$ sudo fstrim -v .
    fstrim: .: the discard operation is not supported`

Comment: On some remote booted Windows machines, the iSCSI target appears as hard disk and on some as SSD. The later works correct by default. No idea why some are handeled as hard disks. You can check that by starting "Drive optimization" (windows very own defragmentation tool).

Comment: Hm. In that case you might want to check and compare the configuration of your block backstores (something like `cd /backstores/block/blah`, `get` in `targetcli`). Maybe you can make it work that way. // Are you sure you mounted the NTFS volume using NTFS-3G? There’s also a kernel-integrated NTFS driver that may take precedence.

Comment: In `targetcli`:
`/backstores/block/some_image> set attribute is_nonrot=1`
`Parameter is_nonrot is now '1'.` does the trick. Now, Windows interprets an iSCSI target as a an SSD